# Pathauto, user profile alias from content profile fields

Tags: 7, users, path-aliases

I created the alias `bartender/profili/[content-profile-profile-profile_name-raw]-[content-profile-profile-profile_surname-raw]` for users.
I want to have '-' between name and surname but it always turns into a white space in my URLs.

Could anybody give me any clue about this?

Answer (score 1):

In the "Automated Alias" settings page there is a fieldset near the top with rules for treating special characters; check it to see how it is treating hyphens.

Comment: As far as I recall, that setting page offers you three choices: remove the character, replace it with a space, keep it. I am not using Drupal 6, and it could be that the option "replace it with a character" is really "replace it with the character you write in the following text field."

Comment: its replace with the "separator character", which you also get to define :)

Comment: I try hyphen : replace by separator (separator is hyphen), hyphen from path auto pattern is lost. I try hyphen: do not replace, hyphen from path pattern is lost. Lost means turn to single space :/